# Change a different Background Color of Chip(material-UI) in a Comments Module when the user is Admin

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I would like to change the background color of Chip when the user is admin , in a Comment Module , like is in the pic this is what i get

```html
<Chip
    label={comment['user.firstname']}
    style={styles.chip}
/>
```

#### Example Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

#### Older Code:

```js
const styles = {
  root: {
    paddingTop: '25px',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  chip: {
    color: 'white',
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '40px',
    lineHeight: '32px',
    margin: '2px 15px',
    minWidth: '50px',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  Button: {
    color: 'white',
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '40px',
    lineHeight: '32px',
    minWidth: '100px',
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code the idea is checking my api for admin user and every admin user have a one color different a normal user

```
import React from 'react';
import TimeAgo from 'react-timeago';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Card from 'components/commons/Card';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Grid  } from '@material-ui/core';
import { getUser } from 'api';


const styles = {
    root: {
    paddingTop: '25px',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
    },
    chip: {
    color: 'white',
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '40px',
    lineHeight: '32px',
    margin: '2px 15px',
    minWidth: '50px',
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
    },

    chipUserAdmin:{
    color: 'white',
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '40px',
    lineHeight: '32px',
    margin: '2px 15px',
    minWidth: '50px',
    backgroundColor:  getUser.id % 0 === 2 ? 'red':'blue' 

    },
    ChipUserNormal:{
    color: 'white',
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '40px',
    lineHeight: '32px',
    margin: '2px 15px',
    minWidth: '50px',
    backgroundColor: 'gray'
    },

    Button: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    padding: '6%',
    paddingTop: '3%',
    paddingBottom: '3%',
    fontSize: '1rem',
    letterSpacing: '0px',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    borderRadius: '2.5px',
    textAlign: 'center'
    },
};

class Comment extends React.Component {

    state = {
    comment: '',
    };

    onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    renderComments(comments) {

    const commentDivs = comments.map(comment => {
        return (
        <div key={comment.id}>
            <div className="row">
            <div className="col comment">{comment.description}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
            <div className="col-9">
                <TimeAgo className="time-ago" date={comment.createdAt} />
            </div>
            <div className="col-3">
                <div style={styles.wrapper}>
                <span className="time-ago">
                    <Chip
                    label={comment['user.firstname']}
                    style={{ backgroundColor: comment.id % 2 === 0 ? 'blue': 'red' || styles.chipUserAdmin }}
                    />
                </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <hr/>
        </div>
        )
    });
    return (
        <div>{commentDivs}</div>
    );
    }

    render() {
    return (
        <Card title="comments">
        <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
            {this.renderComments(this.props.comments)}
            <div className="form-group">
            <textarea
                className="form-control"
                name="comment"
                placeholder="Write a comment"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={this.state.comment}
                rows="3"
            ></textarea>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
            <Button
                onClick={() => this.props.onSubmit(this.state.comment)}
                color="primary"
                variant="contained"
                size="large"
                style={styles.Button}>
                Send
                </Button>
            </div>
        </Grid>
        </Card>
    );
    }
}

Comment.propTypes = {
    comments: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default Comment;
```

Here's an example of what it looks like:

[image: its look like this]

Answer (score 0):

You can add different classNames based on the data. See codesandbox  - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-i8k5h

```
>  <Chip
>             key={data.key}
>             icon={icon}
>             label={data.label}
>             onDelete={handleDelete(data)}
>             className={
>               data.label === "React" ? classes.reactChip : classes.chip
>             }
>           />
```

Here, I am applying different classNames based on whether the label is "React" or not. You can apply the same logic to your code.

***Adding additional suggestions based on the new code:***

```
   backgroundColor:  getUser.id % 0 === 2 ? 'red':'blue'
```

Above code is not correct as it will always return "blue". (any number % 0 is always 'NaN'). I guess that should be the issue in your code. Please fix and let me know if it works.

***Further Edit based on more information :***

Code Sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-5oo5f

I have created a codesandbox mimicing the requirement you have. I am using a JS file that has the user data. I have given logic for setting the chip color based on user's name and also commented out a logic for setting chip color for every alternate user (user.id % 2 === 0). Hope this helps.

Comment: it's not exactly what I want, really I need to use my db to determinate from users, who is admin and who is not admin, in order to change the background color of CHip depending if is admin or not

Comment: Where the data comes from doesnt matter. You can use the same logic even if its from DB. Once you fetch the data, you can check the user type and display accrodingly. Can't help further without seeing more of your code.

Comment: I'm going to send you more code if you can help me with that

Comment: i Change the code look and help me pleasee @VijayMenon

Comment: I have added further comments in my original answer. Please check. Looks like a logical error.

Comment: what do you suggest me , if you can change my code a put the correct way to make it work , I'll appreciate it so much @VijayMenon

Comment: I uploaded a pic in my post for you see how it looks @VijayMenon

Comment: Yes but by user, if you can see just show different color no matter who is admin, the idea is one color for admin user,and one color for normal user

Comment: As per your code, you want gray background for Normal user and red background for admin user?

Comment: Yes thats the idea

Comment: I have added a new Codesandbox which has the logic. Details in the answer. Hope this is what you are looking for.